# jQuery ajax posting to wrong url in rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "analytics/test",
 data: 'correct=' + correct_or_incorrect + '&id=' + correctCharacter[3] + "'"
 });
```

I'm using this to post some information to a rails app. Problem is that it is just posting to the application controller.

How can I get it so that the url is positing to `:controller => 'analytics', :action => 'test'`

Comment: I think your quotes are a bit messed up there.

Comment: You'd get something like `correct=true&id=X'` for `data` -- with that trailing single quote. Your use of both single and double quotes in that string makes one's eyes hurt.

Comment: can you post the contents of your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: That is probably it. I don't have it declared as a resource and do not have default format :)

Comment: nope. I declared it as a resource but it is still going to application/index

Comment: @Sam - Where is the page it's being executed from?

Comment: The page is being executed from localhost/games/tone_colors, but even so no matter what I put for the url it always goes to application controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the answerees know about rails and routes... at least that is what I'm assuming because nobody got close to this one.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/analytics.json', 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: 'success' 
 });
```

That's the answer :) - makes me very happy! Two days to get that one.

The problem was because of the url. I had `:analytics` declared in routes.rb but I didn't have the url correct and that is how rails deals with routes in particular RESTful routing.

Anyone using the code above should not that they can use html xml or whatever but you need to use that as the file extension instead of using .json

Comment: Did the above answer `url: "/analytics/test"` one worked for you?

Answer (score 12):

The path to your url (`analytics/test`) is relative, meaning it will be appended to the "directory" of the url you are working in. E.g. if you are calling this from http://yourhost.com/analytics/demo, you will call http://yourhost.com/analytics/analytics/test, which you probably do not want.

Add a slash to the beginning (so you get `/analytics/test`) and you're fine.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/analytics/test",
    data: 'correct=' + correct_or_incorrect + '&id=' + correctCharacter[3] + "'"
});
```